# Duplex web service in Java

Tags: web-services, duplex

The client connects to a server and then can request it AND the server can invoke some commands on the clients as well.
Is there anything like this in Java?

Comment: What do you mean by duplex web service, care to provide some examples?

Comment: It's really a way to have the server make requests to the clients once they are connected to it.

for example, silverlight has that: 
http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/09/scale-out-of-silverlight-http-polling.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no such thing called duplex webservices, To achieve Client-Server relationship in both direction (duplex as you termed it),  You can expose webservice interface at both the ends for consuming.

Both webservices component acts as Client and Server simultaneously, by exposing consumable web service interface for each other.

See below image for better clarity.

[image]

Comment: Good luck implementing all the little details that go with it though, like threading/concurrency/synchronisation issues.